# Mongo query with $or on 10,000 $geoWithin query completed faster when split into set of 1000 each made in parallel, why?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Basically, My collection has 200,000 documents on which I'm applying $geoWithin among a bunch of selected locations to find documents in these locations.

It looks kind of like:

```
{
    "$or": [
        {
            "location": {
                "$geoWithin": {
                    "$centerSphere": [
                        [
                            -12,   // coordinates from document 1
                            23  
                        ],
                        0.00015
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "location": {
                "$geoWithin": {
                    "$centerSphere": [
                        [
                            -43, // coordinates from document 2
                            51
                        ],
                        0.00015
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

It took several minutes to complete when $or was between 8000-10000 locations, However, when we tried splitting the request into multiple similar requests with lesser locations and running parallelly, we got results quickly at a certain value and **increasing it further again increased the time taken**. **Same with decreasing it drastically.**

My question is why is this happening and how can we figure out the number that optimized the time taken, are some known factors to be considered?

EDIT: adding query planner

100 locations $geoWithin per call, total - 7.66 secs, Query planner + executionStats -  https://hastebin.com/ayudozabaz.bash

1000 locations $geoWithin per call, total - 6.006 secs, Query planner + executionStats -  https://hastebin.com/komalicosu.bash

10000 locations $geoWithin per call, total - 16.384 secs, Query planner + executionStats -  https://hastebin.com/kezamedisa.bash

Comment: Look at the query plans (explain) with execution stats for both queries. I expect you'd find that the database did a collection scan for the slow query and used indexes for the faster queries. In case of expensive comparisons, the threshold where this switch happens may be suboptimal.

Comment: @D.SM I did verify the index being used for the optimal one, but same should be the case as I'm reducing the list of location even further right? This was not what was observed, the time taken again increased when the count decreased.

Comment: Add the queries with execution plans to your question, right now everything is speculation.

Comment: @D.SM Added query planner with trimmed locations to make it more readable and time taken for each of them to complete

Comment: I do not see execution stats.

Comment: @D.SM Sorry, Updated links with executionStats, adding $explain stage didn't show executionStats, I'm doing all this on Spring Data, so it was a little hard to do it exactly the same as query.

Comment: From what I am seeing in the first two explains, it seems a large number of documents are skipped (maybe 5,000 to find your first 100 results) but then there are 1000 consecutive matching documents, therefore it does not take much time to retrieve 1000 documents over 100 documents. The second query took longer than the first query (2000 ms over 400 ms) which is in line with expectations.

Comment: The 7/6 second times you've stated appear to be  not per query which was misleading.

Comment: The 7/6 seconds is the total time taken to complete all parallel requests, for the whole operation 80 of 100 location query, 8 of 1000 location query and 1 of  10000 location query is made. The time is again calculated by code in all cases.

Comment: but this means it was pure luck that 1000 matched locations were received, for a different set of locations 1000 might be very bad. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. If you divided overall time by the # of operations you'd see monotonic growth of time taken vs # of documents requested which would be expected behavior.

Comment: Yes. What you are doing is batch size tuning. You could try randomizing inputs to try to figure out a batch size that works well for most inputs.

Comment: makes sense, Thanks a lot for your inputs, honestly appreciate your help. The query in itself doesn't seem to have any scope of improvement, right?

Comment: I have only surface knowledge of geo queries, so that I can't help with, sorry.

Comment: No worries, thanks a lot. sadly I can't mark the conversation as the answer, could you just make a few line answer so I can close this question and people looking for similar problem can see it and understand or if you don't want to, I'll just create it myself summarizing the conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application queries the database, the following things happen:

1. The query must be constructed. Array appends are generally linear in the size of the array; if an array of conditions is built up one condition at a time, the entire process takes quadratic time in the number of conditions.
2. The query must be sent to the server. Latency is expended per query, so fewer queries means less overhead per document returned.
3. The server must execute the query. There are fixed costs like coming up with a query plan and variable costs including traversing the collection. When more documents are retrieved per query, the overhead per document decreases.
4. The driver must instantiate language-specific data structure for the returned result. Like #1, this can be quadratic in the result size.

As the batch size increases (100 -> 1,000 -> 10,000 in the stated question) the overhead per document in steps #1 and #4 increases and #2 and #3 decreases. It appears that for your query and your data set, batch size of 1,000 produces optimal performance.

The provided execution plans show that the time for each query increases monotonically with input size, which is expected behavior, but the time growth is not linear in input size yielding an apparent optimum batch size somewhere in the middle of the tested range.

With different query structure, query inputs or data in the collection the optimal batch size may be different.

Coming up with a universally optimal batch size is hard. One way of doing so is to randomize inputs and test various input possibilities, to arrive at a batch size that works well in most cases (or, said differently, perform *poorly* in few cases).